# Drupal: images don't show up inside the block (text only)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've added the following code inside a Drupal block, to display an image.

```
<img alt="Fuzion logo" src="sites/all/themes/zen/zen/logo.png" />test<br />
```

I've tried several urls. For none of them I can see the image in my front-end website. The block only contains the text "test".

```
hostingpath/sites/all/themes/zen/zen/logo.png ---> I can see the logo in back-end (editing field, only with this)
sites/all/themes/zen/zen/logo.png
logo.png
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to use an appropriate filter that allows img tags?

Comment: thanks, it is really hard for me to keep in mind all these options, and I sometimes lost a lot of time, but at least Drupal is really cool to do whatever I want

Comment: You can set Full HTML to site-wide default, or better yet, use the Better Formats module to set default input formats for each user role (so you, as admin, could have Full HTML by default, while others have Filtered HTML by default).

Answer (score 0):

Although your question was answered, I have found this also can happen when using the pathauto module with the path to your page set as a "subdirectory"; e.g. `www.example.com/path/to/page`.

As a result, the web server will look for your image at `/path/to/page/sites/all/themes/zen/zen/logo.png` because the URL is relative.

If this occurs, make sure to provide an absolute URL by including a forward slash at the beginning, i.e. `/sites/all/themes/zen/zen/logo.png` instead of `sites/all/themes/zen/zen/logo.png`.

Perhaps this answer will assist someone else with a similar problem.